# Extremizers of repulsive potential

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

This question is about whether one can characterize the extremizers of the Coulomb energy $E:(\mathbb S^{2})^N \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ for $N$ points on the sphere with $x=(x_1,...,x_N)$ where $x_i \in \mathbb S^{2}$

$$E(x):=\sum_{i \neq j} \frac{1}{\Vert x_i-x_j \Vert_{\mathbb R^3}}$$
where $E(x)=\infty$ if two points coincide.

Is the set of critical points known? Obviously it is invariant under rotations, so we may discard rotational symmetry in this question.

Comment: You can say that $\sum_i x_i = 0$. For $N =2, x_2 = - x_1$ and $\|x_1\| = \frac 12$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the [Thomson problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem), which was posed by Thomson in 1904. Global minima are known only for a few very specific values of the number of charges $N$. For example:

- for $N=3$, the solution is the set of vertices of a triangle.
- for $N=4$, 6, or 12, the solution is the set of vertices of the corresponding Platonic solid (tetrahedron, octahedron, icosahedron).
- for $N=5$, the solution is the set of vertices of triangular dipyramid.
- for $N=8$ and for $N=20$, the solutions are **not** the vertices of the corresponding Platonic solids (cube and dodecahedron). These are local minima but not global minima. Intuitively, non-triangular faces leave too much empty space at their centers and are not optimal.
- and so on. The Wikipedia article includes a table of some "good" results for certain values of $N$. In most cases, these are just the best numerical results found to date, with no proof that they are global minima. Some more candidates for global minima for many values of $N$ are presented in [1], and the coordinates of the points can be downloaded from [this website](http://www-wales.ch.cam.ac.uk/~wales/CCD/Thomson/table.html).

Gradient descent works well to find good (possibly local) minima for this problem [2]. There is extensive literature on the topic: you can have a look at the links I provided here and the references therein.

[1] David J. Wales and Sidika Ulker, "Structure and dynamics of spherical crystals characterized for the Thomson problem," *Phys. Rev. B* 74, 212101 – (2006)

[2] Gautam, Simanta and Dmitry Vaintrob. “A Novel Approach to the Spherical Codes Problem.” MIT (2013) Available online [here](https://math.mit.edu/research/highschool/rsi/documents/2012Gautam.pdf).